# Colorize number pairs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the jQuery Stopwatch plugin to track time on a browser based JavaScript game I am developing. This plugin outputs 00:00:00. I need to have each number pair (hours,minutes,second) in diffrent colors.

I also outputs a dummy time before the game starts in HTML (00:00:00). I am able to colorize
each number pair here but using 00 but this does not work on the output from the plugin. How can I do it on that output?

This is the plugin code:

http://pastie.org/2709822

Thankful for all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace line `24` with...

```
return '<span class="hours">' + pad2(hours) + '</span>:<span class="minutes">' + pad2(minutes) + '</span>:<span class="seconds">' + pad2(seconds) + '</span>';
```

Then style the classes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Stick each pair of digits in a `<span>`, then style them however you'd like:

```
<style>
#timer .hours { color: red };
#timer .minutes { color: blue };
#timer .seconds { color: green };
</style>
<div id="timer">
  <span class="hours">00</span>:<span class="minutes">00</span>:<span class="seconds">00</span>
</div>
```